# Stackdriver logging in a Rails app in GKE is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-logging

Ruby 2.3.6, Rails 4.2.6, Stackdriver 0.15.0

Following the directions at https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/ruby, I've added the `stackdriver` gem to `Gemfile`. From what I can tell, I shouldn't **need** to do anything else.

However, I'm not seeing any log messages from within Rails showing up in Stackdriver. I've even tried `exec`ing a shell in the container, running `bundle exec rails console`, and explicitly logging with `Rails.logger.error "this is a log message"`.

`config.google_cloud.use_logging = true` and `config.log_level = :debug`, FWIW.

**UPDATE**: I took a closer look at the logger instance with `pp Rails.logger`, and it contains this:

```
@resource=
  #<Google::Cloud::Logging::Resource:0x0000558b075d1f50
   @labels={:cluster_name=>"onehq-cluster", :namespace_id=>"default"},
   @type="container">,
```

My container is running in the `staging` namespace, which would explain why I'm not seeing log messages. When I look in the Stackdriver log viewer in the `default` namespace, lo, there are logs. Unfortunately, sending all messages to `default` won't do me any good, because I have apps running in two namespaces, and I need to be able to tell them apart.

I tried adding additional configuration:

```
config.google_cloud.logging.monitored_resource.type = "container"
config.google_cloud.logging.monitored_resource.labels = { cluster_name: "my-cluster", namespace_id: "staging" }
```

And now `Rails.logger.error "this is a log message"` doesn't show up *anywhere*.

**UPDATE 2**: After much web searching, I managed to turn up https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-ruby/issues/2025 which suggests that the namespace to which log messages are sent is determined by the value of an environment variable, and that said env var is not being set automatically in GKE containers. (It has supposedly been resolved by https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-ruby/pull/2071 but I don't think that's live yet, at least not in my cluster.) I'll try forcing the env var in my deployment file, and if that works I'll convert the last part of this to an answer.

Comment: Looking at the update it seems like you have resolved this issue. If yes, can you go ahead and post that as an answer for other community users looking at this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much web searching, I managed to turn up https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-ruby/issues/2025 which suggests that the namespace to which log messages are sent is determined by the value of an environment variable, and that said env var is not being set automatically in GKE containers. (It has supposedly been resolved by https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-ruby/pull/2071 but I don't think that's live yet, at least not in my cluster.) I forced the env var in my deployment file, and IIRC that worked. (I no longer have access to that cluster, so I can't verify that.)

Answer (score 0):

Google-Cloud-Env gem has released this morning [the version (1.0.2)](https://rubygems.org/gems/google-cloud-env/versions/1.0.2) you may update your bundle.